# ListItemCollectionPosition returning null

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list which contains more than 50K docs.
So going with SP recommended approach I have used ListItemCollectionPosition to get items in batch of 2000, but the ListItemCollectionPosition  always return null.

```
SPQuery currentQuery = new SPQuery();
  currentQuery.RowLimit = 2000;
  do
   {
     itemCollection= docLib.GetItems(currentQuery); //this statement return less than 2000 items even library have 50K docs
    //some more stuff

    currentQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = itemCollection.ListItemCollectionPosition;
    }while(currentQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition!=null)
```

So could anyone help me out to know the cause of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `currentQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\""`?;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `currentQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";` and `currentQuery.Folder = docLib.RootFolder;`

Also, try minimizing batch size to 100 initially to identify the root cause.